# Detailed Sentiment Score in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

On the StanfordCore NLP website there is the following demo:http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sentiment/rntnDemo.html

The demo gives a sentence a detailed sentiment score from 0 to 4.

I understand how to get a "positive" or "negative" assessment using command line, similar to this:
[Screenshot from corenlp.run showing a positive sentiment analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5s41.jpg)

I have seen this question already, but I am interested how the analysis shown in the attached screenshot is created. [Getting sentiment analysis result using stanford core nlp java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368101/getting-sentiment-analysis-result-using-stanford-core-nlp-java-code)

Is there a way in Stanford CoreNLP to return a score (i.e. 0-4) for a given sentence so show its degree of positivity or negativity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get that kind of info.

Also I should note that the there is a direct mapping:

"Very negative" = 0
"Negative" = 1
"Neutral" = 2
"Positive" = 3
"Very positive" = 4

Here is a sample command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,sentiment -file example-1.txt -outputFormat json
```

In the file `example-1.txt.json` you'll see a lot of sentiment related fields for the sentence, including `sentimentValue`.

There is more info about this at this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/465